# CMake: custom add_executable failing when adding link libraries

Tags: cmake

I'm making a custom cross-platform library that needs to be in native gui mode, so, the add_executable need to have the parameter of `WIN32` or `MACOSX_BUNDLE` depending on the platform. To facilitate this process I created a cmake function:

```
function(add_windowed_executable targetProject targetSources)
    if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Windows")
        add_executable(${targetProject} WIN32 ${targetSources})
    elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Darwin") # MacOS
        add_executable(${targetProject} MACOSX_BUNDLE ${targetSources})
        # ... link with native libraries
    elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL Linux)
        add_executable(${targetProject} ${targetSources})
        # ... link with native libraries
    endif()
endfunction()
```

Now when I try to create an executable with `target_link_library` it gives me the error "Cannot specify link libraries for target "test" which is not built by this project.". It comes down to the fact that the add_windowed_executable is the one that calls the add_executable and not the main file. Is there any way to use this function and allow to link with other libraries, basically replicating the add_executable command?

Main cmake

```
# ...

add_subdirectory("functions")

# ...

add_windowed_executable("test" "src/main.c")
target_link_libraries("test" "otherLibrary") # It's here where the error appears
```

EDIT: tryed with macro instead of function and the error still remains

Comment: So what is the value of `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`?

Comment: In my case is Windows, but it is the operating system name that you are compiling to (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.html#variable:CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME)

Comment: This seems to be a bug: `if(TARGET test) message("the target exists") endif()` prints the message when called in the scope calling the function... maybe a macro works?

Comment: `target_link_libraries` should work if called after `add_executable`. It is unrelated whether `add_executable` is called from the other file or from the function. It seems, something **else** wrong in your code. Please, prepare [mcve].

Comment: The if target test is working, I tryed with the message. BTW, the code is basically there, the function is complete (I still didn't added the native dependencies in the other OSes) the second snipet is my main CMakeLists, just lacking the cmake_minumum_required, project and the set for the c version. The solution that worked with me (see it bellow), is to verify the OS first and then create the function, it works... Maybe it's a windows cmake thing, or the add_executable can't be called inside an if, but, it works and I don't know why... I will try in Linux/MacOS, but it worked under windows.

Comment: The problem was with my custom CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME... (It was being cached I did not forced to set the value)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  add_executable(targetProject
> ```

You added targetProject. Not `test`. You want to use the variable:

```
add_executable(${targetProject} ${targetSources})
```

and the same with `targetSources`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to correct it on the question, but the error on the target_link_libraries still remains

Answer (score -1):

It needs to be done the oposite way. First check the os then create the function or macro:

```
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Windows")
    function(add_windowed_executable targetProject)
        add_executable(${targetProject} WIN32 ${ARGN})
    endfunction()
# ...
endif ()
```

Comment: Why do you expect this to change anything? `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` shouldn't be modified outside of the toolchain file and you're able to see variables defined in an ancestor scope of the function scope from inside the function. Probably your suggestion would result in something a bit more efficient, but probably you won't see a difference. The result should be eactly the same...

Comment: I didn't expected anything, I don't even understand why, but it does work... (maybe it's just a stupid thing about cmake in windows, but I'm not sure, I still not tryed in other platforms)

Comment: I just tested this option to be sure and I could verify it doesn't work...

Comment: It should work on windows... But I found out what the real problem was when creating a repruducble example. I had a cached var with a value that was being setted later (without using force). that var was my custom CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME, so that it could be used to compile a graphical app for android/ios later, so the scope in the if is the one I setted at runtime, but inside the function it was the cached one (the default value that was not an option).